# Python how to change color in a spesific cell in ttk treeview

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview, ttk

I have a simple GUI that show on the screen a table with numbers and I want to colored some spesefic cenlls. someone know how can I do it?

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

def show_table():
    text = ""
    for letter in textDate.get():
        if letter != '/':
            text = text + letter
    print(text)
    number_array = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
    frn = Frame(root)
    frn.place(x=15, y=140)
    tv = ttk.Treeview(frn, columns=(1, 2, 3), show="headings", height="5")
    tv.pack()
    for i in number_array:
        tv.insert('', 'end', values=i)
def save_data():
    date = textDate.get()
    show_table()

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#A2A2A2")
root.title("test")
canvas.pack()
datelable = tk.Label(text="date", bg="#A2A2A2")
datelable.place(x=15, y=50)
textDate = tk.StringVar()
textEntry = tk.Entry(textvariable=textDate)
textEntry.place(x=15, y=70, width=100, height=15)
finishButton = tk.Button(root, text="send", width="10", height="1", bg="#FFFFFF", command=save_data)
finishButton.place(x=15, y=100)
frame = tk.Frame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

> Python how to change color in a spesific cell in ttk treeview

You cannot change the color of a specific cell in the `Treeview` widget. Formatting can only be applied to entire rows. Colors can only be applied with tags, and tags can only be applied to an item as a whole, not a part of an item.

Answer (score 0):

By replacing your tree structure with the grid structure, we can color individual cells example is following

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import random #for random color selection

def show_table():
    text = ""
    for letter in textDate.get():
        if letter != '/':
            text = text + letter
    print(text)
    number_array = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
    for r in range(len(number_array)):
        for c in range(len(number_array[r])):
            colour = "#%06x" % random.randint(0, 0xFFFFFF)
            b = Entry(root, text = StringVar(value=number_array[c][r]), bg = colour)
            b.grid(row = r, column = c)

def save_data():
    date = textDate.get()
    show_table()

root = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height=700, width=700, bg="#A2A2A2")
root.title("test")
datelable = tk.Label(text="date", bg="#A2A2A2")
datelable.place(x=15, y=50)
textDate = tk.StringVar()
textEntry = tk.Entry(textvariable=textDate)
textEntry.place(x=15, y=70, width=100, height=15)
finishButton = tk.Button(root, text="send", width="10", height="1", bg="#FFFFFF", command=save_data)
finishButton.place(x=15, y=100)
frame = tk.Frame(root)
root.mainloop()
```

**Output**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've made a tableview for this exact reason. [tableview.py](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA3EP.png)

https://github.com/Deagek/tableview/blob/main/README.md

The reason I created this is that I needed a widget similar to ttk.treeview but one that allows me to highlight specific cells, which treeview can't do. I also wanted to have a similar look and feel so the feel is somewhat consistent (you can change the column separators should you wish).

tableview is a table that allows for cell highlights and sorting. Similar to treeview, albeit you're unable to move items within. Some features:

You can bind functions to the cells individually and have complete control over each cell.
As with treeview you can also stretch out each column.
Double-clicking on the column separator will snap the column to the minimum size (column header text).
Clicking on the column itself will sort the column.